# Bulk insert stopped working

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

I am trying to import a .csv file from excel into a table in SQL server manager 2014 I got it to work last night and saved the code I used buy then when I tried to insert another table it didn't insert it just kept saying zero rows affected

```
BULK INSERT SchoolModel.dbo.Students
From 'C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\SchoolModeler\StudentTable.csv'
With
      (
         FIRSTROW= 2 ,
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' \n'
      );
```

worked perfectly last night now it doesn't work i figured maybe the data base broke or something who knows so I deleted the whole database and recreated it using the exact same code as before and then went to insert the table the i knew worked and it won't insert either so now im stuck with hours of frustration and i have no idea why it would suddenly stop working?

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsBUo.jpg)

```
 CREATE TABLE Students
(
StudentID  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
LastName   VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL ,
FirstName  VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL ,
Residency  CHAR (1) ,
BirthDate  DATE NOT NULL ,
Gender     CHAR (1) ,
DegreePlan VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
```

) ;
ALTER TABLE Students ADD CONSTRAINT Students_PK PRIMARY KEY ( StudentID ) ;

Fixed with

```
    Use SchoolModel
    Go
    BULK INSERT SchoolModel.dbo.Students
    From 'C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\SchoolModeler\StudentTable.csv'
   With
  (
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  );
```

Comment: Can you please add am example of your csv and the definition of the table?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you edited your csv and excel did changed the separator or the line feeds.

Open your csv with a text editor and verify this.

Maybe it's just from the edit but your sql shows a space befor the separator. This must be removed.

On a Windows os the line feed would be \r\n.

You can verify this by opening your csv with an TextEditor like pspad or an equal one that shows non printable character.

Comment: Used notepad ++ didn't see any space anywhere in the csv and changing it to \r\n didn't do anything either

Comment: But the field delimiter did change.

Comment: yeah i tried using a comma before but you were right it was that space in there that was giving it issues and the fact that it was a | instead of a , can't believe something so small gave me so much frustration lol